# fetching data keeps stop my react-native tab until fetching gets complete

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, react-navigation

I am retrieving data from cloud firestor in `componentDidMount()` method, but  when fetching starts and during fetching data from cloud firestor I am not able to change tab, it takes 8 seconds for less than 100 items docs.
I am using react-navigation and cloud firestor in react-native app.
**Even from cache it takes 8 seconds and I couldnt change tabs during fetching data from cloud firestor, but after fetching I am able to change tabs.**

```
getMessages(){
    db.collection("users/" + this.state.username + "/msgs").orderBy("date", "asc").get().then(snapshot=>{
        this.docs = snapshot.docs;
        for (let i = this.docs.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {

            this.prtcpnts = this.state.currentuser === this.docs[i].data().user.username ? this.state.currentuser + this.docs[i].data().otheruser : this.state.currentuser + this.docs[i].data().user.username;

            if (this.state[this.prtcpnts] === undefined){
                this.setState({
                    [this.prtcpnts]: [this.docs[i].data()]
                });
            }else{
                this.setState(preState => ({ [this.prtcpnts]: [...preState[this.prtcpnts], this.docs[i].data()] }));
            }

        }
    });
}
```

**I want to fetch smothly without stopping my app, I mean I should be able to change tab even during fetching data from cloud firestor.**

Comment: It looks like you’re calling `setState` multiple times as it is inside a `for-loop` It would be better to refactor your code so that you’re only setting state once.

Comment: Hi Andrew, thank you to reply,
How to refactor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by refactoring to the following code.

```
if (this.outState[this.prtcpnts] === undefined){
    this.outState[this.prtcpnts] = [this.docs[i].data()];
}else{
    this.outState[this.prtcpnts] = [...this.outState[this.prtcpnts], this.docs[i].data()]
}

if (i === 0) {
   this.setState({ ...this.state, ...this.outState })
}
```